# Git: Add new filename but not content

Tags: git

In my working tree I renamed a file/folder *and* modified its content.
How do I `add` (and `commit`) only the rename but not the new content?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a similar question asked over on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707465/2601532)

It goes really in-depth on the way Git tracks the name changes, file creations, and deletions.   The quick and dirty answer you're looking for is below.

To  quote from the top answer there:

> What we do now is, first, manually put the file back under its old name, then use git mv to switch again to the new name:
>
> ```
> $ mv new-name.txt old-name.txt
> $ git mv old-name.txt new-name.txt
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the modified renamed file to a temporary file, then `git reset --hard` to undo all your changes.

Then do just the rename via `git mv ...` and commit that change.
Then copy back the changes and remove the temporary file.

In the next step you can add your changes to the renamed file.